# Accessing string from plist returns nil

Tags: objective-c, string, nsdictionary, plist

Here's the code:

```
NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Stones" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *stones = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
NSArray* array = stones[@"StoneArray"];
NSDictionary* dic = array[stoneInt];
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] init];
string = dic[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", stoneInt]];
return string;
```

`stoneInt` being an number from 0-59 (in the default case, it's 11).

When I set a breakpoint at the `return` statement, `stoneInt` is 11 (As it should be), yet `string` is `nil`.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I analyze `dic`, it correctly shows that it's working with key `11` and string `Maze`.

---

Here is the source code for the plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StoneArray</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <string>Ocean</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>2</key>
            <string>Grass</string>
        </dict>
```

this goes on till string 59.  The string I am trying to return (in any of these cases, let's take case 1) is "Ocean".  My `string` object always is `nil`.

Comment: Why do you use `stoneInt` twice in two different ways? You first use it as an index into `array` which gives you a dictionary. You then convert `stoneInt` into a string and use it as a key into the dictionary. That seems really strange.

Comment: I know, I received an error initially when I just had an array of strings.  So when you create the plist, and you see "Item 0, Item 1, etc.", I used them as strings and wrote `NSString* string = array[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", stoneInt]];`

Comment: Either way, it still results in `nil` for the string

Comment: No one can help unless you update your question with the structure of your plist showing the value you are actually trying to get.

Comment: Does my edit help at all?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, turns out the value `stoneInt` was actually one less than the key that I was trying to access.  `stoneInt` was 11, but the key it went to access was identified as 12.